# how to auto connect single database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Normally, when connecting to multiple databases in CodeIgniter, we specify it in `database.php` like

```
$db['default']['host_name']='...'; . . .
$db['group_one']['host_name']='...';
```

and then autoload them in `autoload.php`.

I now want to only have the first group, which is the default, to connect on each page. I want to active the second group manually. I know there is a way to config database connection at runtime, but I do not want that, since I would need to set the config values everytime I connect to the second db.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This might be [useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785134/change-database-connection-at-runtime-in-codeigniter).

Comment: That won't work, If I change the values at runtime, what will happen if I do that in 20 different places and I have to change those values, maybe going from development to production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In database.php file, change the ‘pconnect’ value of all record sets to FALSE. This will make the “default” group as default connection. Other connections you will have to make manually.

For example, put
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
instead of
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;

To connect to another database, you need to specify the group name as follows:
$db2 = $this->load->database(‘new_conn’, TRUE);

Go through following link for more details: 
http://subhra.me/connecting-to-multiple-databases-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 1):

Override in the right place of the controller adjustment model of the active DB configuration.
Write Helper function and change inside db config.